# Are there only 2 places you can declare new generic type parameters in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, type-systems, generics

It's confusing because type declaration and usage both use the `<T>` syntax.  I think there are only 2 places where you can declare new generic types in Java:

## 1. In the definition of a class or interface

```
class MyClass<T> ...
//           ^^^- Type declaration

interface MyInterface<T,U> ...
//                   ^^^^^- Declaring 2 types
```

## 2. Before a static method

```
// The declared type must then be used as a parameter of that method...
static <T> void foo(T t...
//     ^^^

// or as the return type:
static <T> T foo(...
//     ^^^
```

Is that true?  Am I using the right words?  Should I say "introduce" a type variable instead of "declare?"  Things like the following statement worry me:

> It is possible for a constructor to be generic independently of
>   whether the class the constructor is declared in is itself generic.

Source: [Java Language Specification 8.8.4. Generic Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.4)

I'm trying to write up the [limits of Java generics](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/One-off_Examples/wiki/2016.11.17-Java-Generics#type-parameter-declaration-syntax), but I'm only just getting started.

Comment: The method doesn't *have* to be static. It's just that instance methods can reuse the declaration from their class, and it's usually a good idea to do so, therefore you rarely see type declarations on them.

Comment: @KilianFoth instance methods are often limited by inheriting from a super-class or interface, but yes, you're right for instance methods that don't override any other methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Any* method including constructors can take type parameters. I have yet to see a case in Java where you'd want a generic constructor, but it's entirely legal to declare something like

```
class Thingy {
    private final ArrayList<String> items;

    public <A> Thingy(Collection<A> values, Function<A, String> function) {
        items = new ArrayList<>(values.size());
        for (A thing : values)
            items.add(function.apply(thing));
    }
    ...
}
```

And invoke the constructor as `new Thingy(items, x -> x.toString())` when relying on type inference, or as `new<Integer> Thingy(items, x -> x.toString())` when specifying the type parameter explicitly. That's right, the constructor type arguments go after the `new` keyword.

Instance methods may also have type parameters, e.g. I could define

```
class DataSource<T> {
  ...
  public <R> DataSource<R> transform(Function<T, R> transformation) { ... }
}
```

When compared with other type systems with type parameters (C++, C#, Haskell, …), Java doesn't have notable restrictions regarding the places where type parameters may or may not be declared. Instead, this type-erasure based system has notable restrictions on how those type parameters may be used, e.g. regarding arrays, catch clauses, primitive types, and the lack of type aliases.